# Laravel 7 redirect on login based on user value

Tags: authentication, laravel-7

i am using Laravel 7 and the built in Auth to do the login function
In my users table I have a column named roleid I am trying to upon login redirect you to a specific route based on what a users roleid is

I am thinking in my app/Http/auth/LoginController.php I would need to comment out the line that says

```
protected $redirectTo = '/';
```

But then how do I get the users information specifically the value of whats in the column roleid for the user?

Answer (score 0):

Use laravel guards.

Basically you need to add the new role to the `guards` array in `config/auth.php`. Then you can copy-paste the default Auth folder for the new role and modify it so that it makes sense.

See this article for more information:
https://pusher.com/tutorials/multiple-authentication-guards-laravel